# How to navigate between the nested router pages from links that belong to the main router while i am in the nested router pages

Tags: reactjs, nested, react-router, create-react-app

I have a parent router, In its page and the pages it leads to.. there are links that connect to pages of the parent router and pages of the nested router directly.I also have the main page of the nested router which has links that connect to different pages of the nested react router.My problem is that the same links in the parent router pages that lead to nested router pages which work perfectly while i'm NOT INSIDE A NESTED ROUTER PAGE .........don't connect when i'm inside the nested router pages and the only links that work are those that belong to the nested router .
Example:
This is a link in my main router page that leads to one of the pages of the nested react router :

```
<Link  style={{"textDecoration":"none",
        "color":"white"}} to="/profile/favorites"> <FontAwesomeIcon  icon={['fas', 'heart']}/></Link>
```

as long as i'm not in one of the nested router pages (/profile/......) it will connect perfectly to its path BUT IF I am inside any of the nested router pages ........the same link won't work and only links inside the nested router page will work example :

```
<NavLink tag={RRNavLink} className="FontColoring" activeClassName="activeNested" to="/profile/myAds">my adver</NavLink>
```

AS REQUESTED HERE ARE MORE CODE : 
please ignore the arabic letters, you can replace them by bla bla bla ,
Links inside my nested router :

```
<ListGroup className="text-right d-none d-lg-block">
        <ListGroupItem>
        <NavLink tag={RRNavLink} className="FontColoring" activeClassName="activeNested"  to="/profile/main">حسابى</NavLink>
        </ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem>
        <NavLink tag={RRNavLink} className="FontColoring" activeClassName="activeNested" to="/profile/myAds">اعلاناتك</NavLink>
          </ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem>
        <NavLink tag={RRNavLink} className="FontColoring" activeClassName="activeNested" to="/profile/contacted">العقارات المتواصل بخصوصها</NavLink>
          </ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem>
        <NavLink tag={RRNavLink} className="FontColoring" activeClassName="activeNested" to="/profile/favorites">العقارات المفضلة</NavLink>
          </ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem>
        <NavLink tag={RRNavLink} className="FontColoring" activeClassName="activeNested" to="/profile/notifications">الاشعارات</NavLink>
          </ListGroupItem>
      </ListGroup>
```

my nested routing routes

```
<Switch > <Route path="/profile/main" component={Main} /> <Route path="/profile/myAds" component={MyAds} /> <Route path="/profile/contacted" component={Contacted} /> <Route path="/profile/favorites" component={Favorites} /> <Route path="/profile/notifications" component={Notifications} /> <Route component={Notfound} /> </Switch>
```

my parent routes :

```
 <Switch> <Route exact path="/" component={App} /> <Route exact path="/realEstate" component={RealEstate} /> <Route path="/about" component={About} /> <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} /> <Route exact path="/newAds" component={NewAds} /> <Route exact path="/specialAds" component={SpecialAds} /> <Route path="/profile/" component={Profile} /> <Route component={Notfound} /> </Switch>
```

links in my main router js file that direct me to their nested paths as long as i am not in any nested router page :

```
   <PopoverBody className=" pt-4">
          <Link id="PopoverBodyText" style={{"textDecoration":"none"}} onClick={this.toggle3}  to="/profile/main">الملف الشخصى</Link>
        <hr/>
        <Link id="PopoverBodyText" style={{"textDecoration":"none"}} onClick={this.toggle3} 
        to="/profile/contacted">(العقارات المتواصل بخصوصها (0
          </Link>
          <hr/>
          <Link id="PopoverBodyText" onClick={this.toggle3}  style={{"textDecoration":"none"}} 
          to="/profile/notifications">الاشعارات</Link>
```

Comment: Hard to say what might be wrong. Could you post more code?

Comment: i don't really know what would be useful since the project i'm working on has lots and lots of code you can suggest parts if u want , here is my nested routing routes  ```       <Switch >
        <Route path="/profile/main" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/profile/myAds" component={MyAds} />
        <Route path="/profile/contacted" component={Contacted} />
        <Route path="/profile/favorites" component={Favorites} />
        <Route path="/profile/notifications" component={Notifications} />
        <Route component={Notfound} />
        </Switch>  ```

Comment: here are my parent routes : ```    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route exact path="/realEstate" component={RealEstate} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route exact path="/newAds" component={NewAds} />
        <Route exact path="/specialAds" component={SpecialAds} />
        <Route  path="/profile/" component={Profile} />
        <Route component={Notfound} />
        </Switch>```

Comment: Try to reconstruct the error with the simplest possible example and then put your code here. I can not help much without code

Comment: @DominikTargosz Please check the post again ..... i added all related code